# How to route Lumen for single page app

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using Lumen + Vue js to build an app.
I have this code in routes.php

```
$app->get('{any}', function ()  {
    return view('vue', []);
});
$app->get('/', function ()  {
    return view('vue', []);
});
```

This works great for /login, /users, /anything . But when I add a subroute like /users/agents or /a/b, /a/b/c -> anything with more than one slash it gives me the 404 from lumen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the 404 error because `{any}` will not catch the parameters that contain slash. I order to make it do so, you need to add a pattern:

```
$app->get('{any:.+}', function ()  {
    return view('vue', []);
});
```

Comment: Now it gives me 'HTTP ERROR 500' 'example.com is unable to handle this request' on every route

Comment: See (Browser Dev Tools -> Network (your ajax request) -> Preview) for more details.

Comment: Status Code:500 Internal Server Error . Preview Failed to load response data

Comment: I cant' help you this way :S !

Comment: too bad man :( can it be that the get function does not return an object?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116856/discussion-between-ismail-rbouh-and-john).